# how to create multiple jars with usage specific xml copied to jar - Maven

Tags: java, jar, maven-plugin

I am trying to migrate from ANT build to Maven build setup for a very simple codebase setup:

`src > Java Classes`

`conf > META-INF > 3 xml files namely dbConnect-jboss.xml, dbConnect-weblogic.xml, dbConnect-ooc.xml`

The goal is to create 3 JARs : 
`project-jboss.jar, project-weblogic.jar, project-ooc.jar`

where each jar will have `META-INF/dbConnect.xml`, copy of relevant `conf/META-INF/dbConnect-xxx.xml`.

I tried with [maven-jar-plugin + maven-antrun-plugin ] but the issue is the maven-antrun-plugin does the copy only one time so suppose project-jboss.jar created first then all the rest jars will have same dbConnect.xxx.xml

I need to get a way - how to invoke the copy of dbConnect.xml file via maven-antrun-plugin each time for the respective JAR creation.

[screenshot for maven-ant and maven-jar plugin section from pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y25jZ.png)

Comment: Hi. Would you be so kind in adding the contents of the pom.xml in the question instead of putting a screenshot? It helps in copying stuff and trying to solve your issue faster instead of writing everything by hand *winky face*

Comment: I tried - bit new to SoF - the comment box suggesting i have lots of code and not allowing me to post

Comment: Just click on `edit` on your question and replace your screenshot with the pom.xml contents.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all those who tried to help me out here, appreciate your helping gesture.
I opted maven-assembly-plugin for the needful.

The following snippet would explain my approach:

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- To suppress default JAR creation -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase />
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Then I created respective assembly xml files for each relevant JAR expected. For example, one of assembly xmls:

```
<assembly ....>
<id>jboss</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <!-- Avoid getting relevant dependencies included in JAR -->
        <includes>
            <include>com.vibrant:streamliner.reposerv</include>
        </includes>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/config/META-INF/dbConnect-jboss.xml</source>
        <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
        <destName>dbConnect.xml</destName>
    </file>
</files>
```

Then, I added profile in pom.xml:

```
<profile>
    <id>create-all-jars</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>pom-assembly-jboss.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>pom-assembly-weblogic.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>pom-assembly-ooc.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

And, once we execute following - 3 Jars get created:

```
mvn -P create-all-jars clean package
```